# How to resize image in div to cover?

Tags: css, image, height, width

Ok, I guess you've heard this one before... I tried to find a solution, but can't find one. I have a container that covers the left 50% of a screen. Inside the container I want an image to cover the space, and not to strech. 
Css at this moment is:

```
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

Please help!!!

Comment: set the image as a background image on the container and set it's `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

• If you have an image **larger than the space you want it to cover** and you use an img tag to do that, add this to your css:

```
img {width: auto; height: auto;}
```

• If, instead, you use a div to place the image as a background-image, use this:

```
div {
    background-image: url("yourimage.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as a background and use the following properties:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/upn7jwfs/

Answer (score 0):

add img inside your div and set width and height for image in 100%;

```
<div> <img src=""/> </div>
```

css

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```